# array of spaced numbers in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I want to do an array in Matlab kinda like this

```
a=[1,2,3,4,147,148,149,150,151,294,295...]
```

that means , interval of 4 numbers , spaced by one , and when it reaches the last numbers of the subset of 4 numbers , add 143 to the last number and so on
I tried this for -loop but it's not working

```
interval=zeros(1,12)
begin=1
cont=1
for i=begin:1:296
    interval(cont)=i;
    cont=cont+1

    if (i==begin+3)
        begin=i+143;
        i=begin;
        
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you share what you code actually outputs?  I suspect your issue is due to trying to change the loop variable within the loop.

Comment: The second subrange has 5 numers, not 4. Is that correct? If so, what's the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do it. I currently have no Matlab at hand, so I cannot check whether I got all numbers corrects.

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] + (145*[0 1 2 3 4]'+[1 2 3 4 5]') 
X = X(:);
```